# Power BI Average of Two Measures ....Total Time/ Sum of Files

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there a way to get the average of two measures where one is total amount of time and the other value is a whole number?

I have a table where each row has a file number and how much time that file was opened.  I need to present the average amount of time spent for all files opened.

I have two measures, TotalTimeSpent:

```
TotalAH = FORMAT(SUM('TS'[TimeforCalc]), "hh:mm:ss"
```

and TotalFiles as a distinct count whole number.

These two calculations are currently card visuals, so I wanted a third card to show Average Amount of Time Spent per File

I thought this would be obvious even for my beginner knowledge but trying quick measures doesn't allow me to pick other measures and a new column of just division does not work.

Do I need to create a new table to have running totals of each column?

Comment: If you have TotalTimeSpent and a measure for the TotalFiles, you can create a new measure for average amount of time spent per file.

Comment: AverageTimePerFile = 
DIVIDE(
    SUMX('YourTable', TIMEVALUE('YourTable'[TotalTimeSpent])),
    SUM('YourTable'[TotalFiles])
)

Answer (score 0):

Your `TotalAH` measure is formatted as a string. Consider having two measures, one where it stays numeric, and the other for text. Example:

```
TotalAH # = SUM('TS'[TimeforCalc])

TotalAH txt = FORMAT([TotalAH #], "hh:mm:ss")
```

Be aware that "hh:mm:ss" is good up to 24 hours, anything more will lose the "day" portion.

Your average would then look like:

```
AVG Time Per File # = DIVIDE([TotalAH #], [TotalFiles])

AVG Time Per File txt = FORMAT([AVG Time Per File #], "hh:mm:ss")
```